# I must plot each function for each item in my list, not working

Tags: python, plot, graph

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

fig = plt.figure
xvals = np.linspace(0.4, 2, 100)    # generate x-values


def f1(xvals):
    return (1. / 3.) * (-1. + xvals**3)

def f2(xvals):
    return (1. / 2.) * (-1. + xvals**2)

def f3(xvals):
    return -1. + xvals

def f4(xvals):
    return 2.303*(np.log10(xvals))

def f5(xvals):
    return 1. - (1./xvals)

def f6(xvals):
    return (1. / 2) - (1. / (2.*xvals**2))

def f7(xvals):
    return (1. / 3.) - (1./(3.*xvals**3))


functions = [f1(xvals), f2(xvals), f3(xvals), f4(xvals), f5(xvals), f6(xvals), f7(xvals)]
plotters = [ plt.plot, plt.loglog, plt.semilogx, plt.semilogy ]


for plot in plotters:
    for func in functions:
        plot(xvals, func)

plt.xlabel("x"); plt.ylabel("f(x)") # add axis labels
myTitle = "Compare shapes of various functions of x through (1,1)"
plt.title(myTitle)                  # add plot title
plt.legend(loc = "lower right")     # add legend
plt.show()
```

This is supposed to create four graphs for each graphing method in 'plotters', it only creates 1 graph, specifically plotters[1] and/or plotters[3] (They look the same). Its a lab that i need to do for school. I am new to code. The console doesn't give me any Type Errors.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create subplots. Now, all your plots are happening on a single set of axes so each one overwrites the last.

```
fig1 = plt.figure(figsize=(7, 10)) #you can set figure sizes too!!
#create axes for sub plots
ax1 = plt.subplot(221)
ax2 = plt.subplot(222)
ax3 = plt.subplot(223)
ax4 = plt.subplot(224)

#actual plotting
for func in functions:
    ax1.plot(xvals, func)
    ax2.loglog(xvals, func)
    ax3.semilogx(xvals, func)
    ax4.semilogy(xvals, func)
# legends ( you don't have any)
for ax in [ax1, ax2, ax3, ax4]:
    ax.legend(loc="lower right")
#set titles for each axes
ax1.set_title('Regular plot')
ax2.set_title('Loglog plot')
ax3.set_title('Semilogx plot')
ax4.set_title('Semilogy plot')

plt.show()
```

This is what is looks like:[image]